# Allow inclusion of file in php but forbid reading/editing by user

Tags: files, permissions

I have a file.php that needs the be kept in secrecy, so its permissions are 700. What I'd like to do is maintain these permissions 700 but allow the inclusion of the file in other files. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just so you know, if you really want a file to be secret, you should encrypt it, not just set basic permissions.

Answer (score 1):

To include a file, it must be open (read), there is no difference between reading a file to see it and reading a file to include it. So the only way is to make the owner of the secred file equal to the user that runs the script that includes the file.

If you want the same user to not be able to open a file, but be able to include it, then your request makes no sense and thus has no solution.

Comment: How can i define the user that opens the scripts in PHP files then?

Comment: Web servers usually run as a separate user, maybe `http` or `apache` or something like that. Check your configuration - I don't know what are you running.

Comment: That's not the *only* way. You could make the group the same (then `chmod 0640`/`0750` if it really has a reason to be `+x`). Or use ACLs to grant one specific user or group `+r`, even thought that user/group doesn't own the file. Both of those methods may make more sense, depending.

Comment: @derobert how exactly can this be done to the file?

Comment: Sure, having 060 and group set is the same concept as 600 and having a user set. My point is, that if the OP wants the same user to be able to include, but not read, that's impossible.

Comment: @orion I know that Orion, but what I want is the file to be read by php include but not by other users (I know this isn't correct technically since the file readers are considered 'users'). How can I define the file group to the one that normally runs php scripts like you said 'http' or 'apache'? I'm running nginx...

Comment: @orion TYSM ORION ;(((

Comment: `chgrp http <filename>` (or `chown` for setting the user).